# How to set Min and Max range for datetime calender

Tags: jquery

I am using the calender from the link: http://razum.si/jQuery-calendar/TimeCalendar.html

but i want one extra function setting min and max date range.

i have two input feilds and set the range with one another.

in my JS i have like this

```
$("#datepicker1").calendar({ fieldSettings :customRange});
$("#datepicker2").calendar({ fieldSettings :customRange});

function customRange(input) {
    return { 
        minDate : (input.id == 'datepicker2' ? (getDate(jq11('#datepicker1').val())) : null),
        maxDate :(input.id == 'datepicker1' ? (getDate(jq11('#datepicker2').val())) : null)
    } 
}
```

but it is not working. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indention never hurts...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the date range, you may use the `Datepicker` widget from [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max). There is a full code sample on the page, but I'll paste an excerpt of it's usage:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes i can use. But in my application i am already using dateTime picker of v2.5 jquery_calender.js.
Using same version i would like to set date range. 
Please help me.